# Exc_bad_access NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _disposeObjects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode8, exc-bad-access

I developing swift application which included Core data and Alamofire. I'm struggling to solve this issue for almost a day.

Below is a screen shot after app is crashing and it happens randomly. I know this information might not enough, please mention if anyone need more details. At least guide me to track this issue.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Its mainly crashing after this method reload tableview function.

```
func reloadTable(){
    print("reloadTable called")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest < NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Jars")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.jarlist = NSArray()

        do{
            self.jarlist = try context.fetch(request) as NSArray
            print("Check 11")
        }catch{

        }
        self.ArrayPopulator("")
        print("Check 12")
        self.JarsTable.reloadData()
        print("Check 13")
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the code where the app crashes. You can put Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: What does your core data stack look like? are you using `NSPersistentContainer`?

Comment: I'm not using NSPersistentContainer.

Answer (score 3):

So looking at your stack trace it looks like you are using your managed context on thread 2.

A `NSManagedObjectContext` cannot be used on multiple threads, you must have one for every thread (queue) that you want to use it on. It is only safe to pass object identifiers between threads.

Can you double check that the objects your are wanting to dispose of in your `NSOperation` were retrieved on the same operation queue that you are trying to remove them on?

You will want to pass only the ids to the operation and have it rehydrate them from it's own managed object context.

**EDIT:** Looking closer this appears to be an internal queue managed by CoreData, so possibly this is not your doing?